# SoftLayer CLI Command or REST API to Boot from ISO Image

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a SoftLayer CLI command (or REST API) to boot an existing VSI from an ISO Image Template? This exists in the GUI as "Boot from Image", but not able to find any documentation on anything close that exists.

Closest CLI command I could find was the OS Reload command
"slcli vs reload" and, unfortunately, it only works with Standard Image Templates, not ISO Image Templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following please:

### Python Command Line (SLCLI)

> slcli call-api Virtual_Guest mountIsoImage --id $vsiId $diskImageId

e.g:

```
slcli call-api Virtual_Guest mountIsoImage --id 22892000 14121207
```

---

### Rest:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/22892000/mountIsoImage

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      14121207
   ]
}
```

**Replace**: $user, $apiKey, 22892000(vsiId) and 14121207(diskImageId) with your own information

---

> **Updated**

---

According to the exception that you got, it seems that you are not sending a **diskImageId** valid, if you wish to get the **diskImageId** from your image template, try the following:

### Python Command Line (SLCLI)

```
slcli call-api Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group getChildren
--id $templateGroupId --mask=blockDevices.diskImageId
```

to get more details about disk images from the image template:

```
> slcli call-api Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group getChildren
> --id $templateGroupId --mask=blockDevices.diskImage
```

Replace **$templateGroupId** with your image id

---

### Rest:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/$templateGroupId/getChildren?objectMask=mask[blockDevices[diskImage]]
```

Method: Get

**References**:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::mountIsoImage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/mountIsoImage)
- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::getChildren](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getChildren)

Comment: Got an error when running slcli call-api Virtual_Guest mountIsoImage --id xxxxxx xxxxxx
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue): Invalid value provided for 'diskImageId'.

Comment: I was trying to use a Private ISO Template from Object Storage, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Review the **Updated** section in my answer, please make double check that you are sending a valid **diskImageId**

Comment: Sorry didn't get a chance to update, I figured that out that I was using ImageId instead of diskImageId. Thanks!